# Kotlin on Android: How to use LiveData from a database in a fragment?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, type-mismatch

I use MVVM and have a list of data elements in a database that is mapped through a DAO and repository to ViewModel functions.

Now, my problem is rather banal; I just want to use the data in fragment variables, but I get a type mismatch.

The MVVM introduces a bit of code, and for completeness of context I'll run through it, but I'll strip it to the essentials:

The data elements are of a data class, "Objects":

```
@Entity(tableName = "objects")
data class Objects(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "object_name")
    var objectName: String
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null
}
```

In ObjectsDao.kt:

```
@Dao
interface ObjectsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM objects")
    fun getObjects(): LiveData<List<Objects>>
}
```

My database:

```
@Database(
    entities = [Objects::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class ObjectsDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getObjectsDao(): ObjectsDao
    companion object {
        // create database
    }
}
```

In ObjectsRepository.kt:

```
class ObjectsRepository (private val db: ObjectsDatabase) {
    fun getObjects() = db.getObjectsDao().getObjects()
}
```

In ObjectsViewModel.kt:

```
class ObjectsViewModel(private val repository: ObjectsRepository): ViewModel() {
    fun getObjects() = repository.getObjects()
}
```

In ObjectsFragment.kt:

```
class ObjectsFragment : Fragment(), KodeinAware {

    private lateinit var viewModel: ObjectsViewModel

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(ObjectsViewModel::class.java)

        // I use the objects in a recyclerview; rvObjectList
        rvObjectList.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, gridColumns)
        val adapter = ObjectsAdapter(listOf(), viewModel)

        // And I use an observer to keep the recyclerview updated
        viewModel.getObjects.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            adapter.objects = it
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }
}
```

The adapter:

```
class ObjectsAdapter(var objects: List<Objects>,
                     private val viewModel: ObjectsViewModel):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ObjectsAdapter.ObjectsViewHolder>() {
// Just a recyclerview adapter
}
```

Now, all the above works fine - but my problem is that I don't want to use the observer to populate the recyclerview; in the database I store some objects, but there are more objects that I don't want to store.

So, I try to do this instead (in the ObjectsFragment):

```
var otherObjects: List<Objects>
// ...
if (condition) {
    adapter.objects = viewModel.getObjects()
} else {
    adapter.objects = otherObjects
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

And, finally, my problem; I get type mismatch for the true condition assignment:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is LiveData<List> but List was expected

I am unable to get my head around this. Isn't this pretty much what is happening in the observer? I know about backing properties, such as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data#5), but I don't know how to do that when my data is not defined in the ViewModel.

Comment: You want to filter the list returned from database based on a condition. Right?

Comment: No, I sometimes want to fill the recyclerview from the database, and sometimes I want to fill it with some other data. As an example, I sometimes want to see favorite files, which I have saved in the database, and sometimes I want to see all files, which I read from the file system; it's the same recyclerview, but I get data from different places.

Comment: And is it a one-time thing or can this be changed? I mean, do you decide the list once and don't change it till the app lives OR do you switch between these lists?

Comment: I switch - typically by toggling a switch button; sometimes you want to see favourites, and sometimes you want to see everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need something to switch data source. We pass switching data source event to viewModel.

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    viewModel.switchDataSource(isChecked)
}
```

In viewModel we handle switching data source

(To use switchMap include  `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0"`)

```
class ObjectsViewModel(private val repository: ObjectsRepository) : ViewModel() {
    // Best practice is to keep your data in viewModel. And it is useful for us in this case too.
    private val otherObjects = listOf<Objects>()
    private val _loadDataFromDataBase = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    // In case your repository returns liveData of favorite list
    // from dataBase replace MutableLiveData(otherObjects) with repository.getFavorite()
    fun getObjects() = _loadDataFromDataBase.switchMap {
        if (it) repository.getObjects() else MutableLiveData(otherObjects)
    }

    fun switchDataSource(fromDataBase: Boolean) {
        _loadDataFromDataBase.value = fromDataBase
    }
}
```

In activity/fragment observe `getObjects()`

```
viewModel.getObjects.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    adapter.objects = it
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```kotlin
var displayDataFromDatabase = true // Choose whatever default fits your use-case

var databaseList = emptyList<Objects>() // List we get from database
val otherList = // The other list that you want to show

toggleSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked -> 
    displayDataFromDatabase = isChecked // Or the negation of this
    // Update adapter to use databaseList or otherList depending upon "isChecked"
}

viewModel.getObjects.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { list ->
    databaseList = list
    if(displayDataFromDatabase)
        // Update adapter to use this databaseList
}
```

Comment: You can also move these new variables to your ViewModel so that they survive config changes.

Comment: I try, but I think I get something wrong? First, I have to specify type for the databaseList (= emptyList<Objects>()), and as the getObjects doesn't take arguments, I get an error about too many arguments. Also the list parameter needs a type specified. And val cannot be reassigned :-) I'm trying to modify it to avoid errors, but wouldn't this still end up assigning LiveData<List> to List?

Comment: 1. Yes, you need to specify the type for the list. 2. My bad, i typed `viewModel.getObjects(viewLifeCyclerOwner)` instead of `viewModel.getObjects.observe(viewLifecycleOwner)`. 3. `databaseList` is a `var`. 4. No, we aren't assigning LiveData<List> to List, we are assigning the value of live data (which is a list) to `databaseList`